# .NET Core Identity API with permission based auth

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm new at Identity API but in my web application: Institution users creates other users for own institution and and they want to decide who see this page or not.My controller methods like this ;

```
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But also user's have permissions to do any actions like this enum and enum is bigger than 50;

```
    public enum PermissionTypes
    {
        UserCreate = 1,
        UserEdit = 2,
        UserDelete = 3,
        ....
    }
```

And i do some research and found policy based authorization but when you create a new policy you must declare at Startup.cs and its not good for me because when you do that you always publish new codes in production.What i need is something like that ;

```
    [CustomAuth(PermissionTypes.UserCreate)]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is there any solution for this situation ?

Comment: I am going to give you a start.....

Comment: Please check my answer and if you need any help implementing send me a private message and I will help you out.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as possible also i might be use AspNetRoleClaims for this.What do you think about it ?

Comment: You could use Claims... But it becomes even more cumbersome.  In any case there are many ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm so confused right now :)

Comment: There is no concept of "Permissions" in AspNetCore Identity.  So you have to cook your own.  My answer modifies the existing "Role Authorization" to use ANY logic you want instead of the default Role Based logic.  I used it all the time when I need granular permissions.  Claims can be used for this but then you will need a claim for each "permission" and so on and it might end up being more difficult.  With my solution you create your own logic and piggy back on the "Authorize" attribute.  But your code will decide if the user has or not the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many ways to do this.  A lot of people recommend claims and policy based security... I personally found this approach a little "stiff".

So instead I do this a little different:

First create a class like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bamboo.Web.CoreWebsite.Membership
{
  public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesAuthorizationRequirement>
  {
    private readonly IUserStore<CustomUser> _userStore;        

    public PermissionHandler(IUserStore<CustomeUser> userStore)
    {
      _userStore = userStore;         
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
      if(context == null || context.User == null)
        return;

      var userId = context.User.FindFirst(c => string.CompareOrdinal(c.Type, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) == 0);//according to msdn this method returns null if not found

      if(userId == null)
        return;

      // for simplicity, I use only one role at a time in the attribute
      //but you can use multiple values
      var permissions = requirement.AllowedRoles.ToList();

      var hasPermissions = //here is your logic to check the database for the actual permissions for this user.
                           // hasPermissions is just a boolean which is the result of your logic....

      if(hasPermissions)
        context.Succeed(requirement);//the user met your custom criteria
      else
        context.Fail();//the user lacks permissions.
    }
  }
}
```

Now inject the PermissionHandler in your startup.cs file like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          // Custom Identity Services
          ........

          // custom role checks, to check the roles in DB 
          services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();

//the rest of your injection logic omitted for brevity.......
    }
```

Now use it in your actions like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = PermissionTypes.UserCreate)]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
   return View();
}
```

Notice I did not create a custom attribute... Like I said there is many ways to do this.
I prefer this way because is less code and there is no hard-coded policies or claims or any other complexities and you can make it 100% data driven.

This is a complex subject so there might be extra tweaks necessary for it work.

Also I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 which might be different than 3.0.

But it should give you a way to do permission based Authorization.

Comment: It works. But I wonder that system has to query each client request. Is there any way to store permission to UserStore and get it from here?

Comment: @ThanhLD my guess is that you can store it where ever you want.  In my case I use a database or even an JSON Api when I need to centralize for multiple client apps.  I also do something similar for other Indentity operations

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Roles within your action.

[ASP .NET Core Identity Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: How does this answer the question? He is asking for permission based approach.  you dont have to use "roles"... You can but you dont have to.

Comment: but users also create a new role and also you're writing attribute on controllers.What  should i do for when my clients create new a role?

Comment: I think that is misunderstanding. The roles define permissions and should be semantically related to your actions. You cannot create role with saying its security meaning. Indstead of you have e.g. CRUD actions and related roles create, read, update, delete. The administrator gives the user at runtime the groups of roles (permissions).

Comment: The application roles visible to your users could be only a named group of your programatically roles.

Comment: @OndrejRozinek you are wrong.... That is just the "vanilla" way to do it... It is very limited for very simplistic applications.... I have worked on many complex websites that require granular permissions way beyond "CRUD" based on roles.  ASP.NET Core defines other ways of doing this like "Claims".  But I rather use an attribute and database driven permission approach that has nothing to do with ROLES.. As a matter of fact my last project had no roles at all and I used ASP.NET Core identity to enforce permissions on each Action in the controllers.

Comment: @Darkonekt I disagree with you. Your proposed solution is fully ROLES management. In fact you shouldn't use then base class AuthorizationHandler<ROLESAuthorizationRequirement> of your class PermissionHandler and you wouldn't to operate with requirement.AllowedROLES and utilize [Authorize(ROLES= PermissionTypes.UserCreate)].  Also the roles are at default persist in the table AspNetRole, so I don't understand what you mean with database driven permission. I didn't mention that is only one solution but one of more possible, which actually has been confirmed with your proposed solution.

Comment: It is NOT based on roles.... It is based on whatever you want... Did you actually read the code? inside the HandleRequirementAsync method you can use ANY logic you want! You can treat the string passed in as a granular permission! You can check a database and use any logic you desire without using any role at all. You can have permissions assigned to the user rather than roles.

Comment: @OndrejRozinek in my solution you do not need a table AspNetRole at all...!

Comment: @OndrejRozinek you obviously did not understand the code!  You see this line of code: var hasPermissions = //here is your logic to check the database....... That is where you do ANY logic you want.... I basically replace the "default role validation" logic to use any logic you desire... As a matter of fact that code is being used by an application that has NO roles.  It has dozens of permissions in and a user can be assigned very specific permissions.

Comment: @Darkonekt No, you are using still the role APIs and interfaces to overwrite functions with your own behavior or extend the functionalities. But the API remains same and belonging to the same aspect architecture in identity. It's OK and it's supposed to do it, but I wouldn't call it that is quite another thing. You can change the persistence layer and it is so designed. That's has same semantic for definition of permission and its called in the same time of application life cycle, you can see it so.

Comment: @OndrejRozinek now you are argument is merely semantics.... It is not using the AspNetRoles at all... Not the table nor the functionallity ( which was overwritten by the code provided. ) So I understand you are confused by the nomenclature. But the actual functionality is not Role Based any more... Now it is custom based.

Comment: @Darkonekt: The Identity is mainly API, mentioned also in the description of issue. The concrete implementation is up to you and it is flexible per its definition. I found very bad practice if you would use the API for another its meaning, e.g. Login for Logout,. Either you misunderstood and misused API for another meaning if you are writing its another thing and different, or you are not calling it right. As I understood it's still related to API role abstractions and permission meaning, so it's is based role or you misused API?

Comment: @Darkonekt: No, the definitions are mentioned the declaration of interfaces and types. You are disallowed to change signatures of interfaces, methods, properties or change closed functions in the types in one version of the API. Is it this absurd for you? The roles types and interfaces (API) are dedicated for role-based authorization. So you misused these concrete types for different purpose. I think the claims are more suitable for usage. You should not the attribute with Role for different purpose like this Roles = PermissionTypes.UserCreate and saying that is not role.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys , i think i did it :) This is the github [Source](https://github.com/ilya-chumakov/PaperSource.AspNetCoreAuthorization)